# Checkbox and label not displaying in same line

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dojo

I am using below mentioned code for creating checkboxes and labels dynamically. But label and checkboxes are not aligning in same line. Can anyone guide what is wrong in below code?

```
dojo.require("dijit.form.CheckBox");
dojo.ready(function(){    
   var widgetNode = dojo.doc.createElement("DIV");
    chk = dojo.create("input", {id:"cbox", type:"checkbox"}, widgetNode);
    lbl = dojo.create("label", {innerHTML:"Check me", "for":"cbox"}, widgetNode);
    dojo.style(lbl, "marginLeft", ".5em");
var cbWidget = new dijit.form.CheckBox({}, chk);
    cbWidget.startup();
    cbWidget.domNode.appendChild(lbl);
dojo.place(cbWidget.domNode, "container");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually put the checkbox inside the label instead of using the `for="zzz"` syntax. Just is a bit easier. I think the easiest way to get what you want is to include a [dijit theme](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/themes.html). Including one of the themes like Claro will automatically have the styles to put the checkbox inline. Example here: http://jsbin.com/fusijoc/1/edit?html,js,output